# Python: smallest number in list

Tags: python, arraylist

I'm new to python and i don't know how to find the smallest number in each array. The input is `[ [2], [3, 4], [6, 5, 7], [4, 1, 8, 3] ]` and the output should be `[2, 3, 5, 1]`. I have try this:

```
x = [ [2], [3, 4], [6, 5, 7], [4, 1, 8, 3] ]
minimal = x[0]
  for i in range(len(x)):
      if (x[i]< minimal):
          minimal = x[i]
print(minimal)
```

And the output that i got is `[2]`, i have no idea about this. Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to get individual lists from list `x` using `for lst in x:`. Then we find the minimum value of that list using `min()` function & append it to your `minimal` list using `minimal.append(min(lst))`, then print the final `minimal list` Now you will have your output as `[2, 3, 5, 1]`

Now try & understand this code:

```
x = [ [2], [3, 4], [6, 5, 7], [4, 1, 8, 3] ]

minimal = []

for lst in x:
    minimal.append(min(lst))
print(minimal)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can simply iterate through the nested list and append the minimum values for each of the list item.

```
smallest = []
for listItem in x:
    smallest.append(min(listItem))
```

Now, `smallest` list should be the expected output list.

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
list(map(lambda x:min(x),[[2], [3, 4], [6, 5, 7], [4, 1, 8, 3] ]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works, but can you explain how the code works?

Comment: @Oogway the `map` function will iterate over the `list` and apply the paramtre `function` on every element in the list in this case by using the keyword `lambda` I define a function that return the `min` of a `list`

Comment: @alex you could simply give an explanation of my answer if you really care instead of wasting time by trying to prove you re right

Comment: @to_data Sure, I could have. Why would I though? It's your answer, your responsibility, your reputation. But even if I did, you probably wouldn't even notice it and repeat this behavior in the future. This way you'll hopefully remember what consists of a solid answer.

Comment: btw I wonder who deleted all my comments, cause it wasn't me.